# Linq 2 SQL - A Better way of doing this

Tags: c#, generics

I have a repository base class that gets called from my controllers in my mvc application

Each controller gets it own repository

like this

```
public class ServiceRepository : Bluegrass.Mvc.RepositoryBase<Models.Service>
{
    public ServiceRepository()
    {
        this._db = new iSppms.Models.iSppmsDataContext();
    }
}
```

And gets used like

```
internal DataAccess.ServiceRepository repository =
        new iSppms.DataAccess.ServiceRepository();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewData = new ViewData.ServiceIndexViewData(
            repository.GetItems<Models.Service>());
        return View(viewData);
    }
```

Where I am wanting to do is not have to pass the model through as the RepositoryBase is already of type Models.Service

I am looking for a better way to structure this.

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    public DataContext _db;

    public List<T> GetItems<T>() where T : class, Interfaces.IModel
    {
        var table = _db.GetTable<T>();
        var data = table.Where(t => !t.Deleted);

        return data.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the `IModel` bit to `RepositoryBase<T>`, and make `GetItems<T>` non-generic? Note: it is already a bad idea to re-use the generic token `T` (which is **different** in `GetItems`):

```
public class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class, Interfaces.IModel
{
    public DataContext _db;

    public List<T> GetItems()
    {
        var table = _db.GetTable<T>();
        var data = table.Where(t => !t.Deleted);

        return data.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this [Repository Base Class](https://devermind.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/a-linq-disconnected-mode-abstract-base-class/) article could help?